# Any simple way to list the contents of a directory in a web server if the http server does not have directory listing enabled?

Tags: c#, http

If directory listing is not enabled, in say IIS, apache or Njinx you can still access resources if the regular expression entered in the browser matches and item in the directory - i.e. index.html, mypic.jpg etc. So one could list the contents of a directory not set to list everything by just trying all different regular expressions and listing the ones that were valid matches. Is there an easier way to do it than this?

Comment: Against what would you want to match regular expressions? For example a regex matching n-times a to z followed by a dot and htm will have unlimited matched if n is allowed to grow forever. So just trying to download all possible combinations is kind of a DOS. Maybe just elaborate a little further on what you want to achieve with this approach. Maybe you can write a webservice to access the server's data?

Comment: I only want to list the contents of the directory in a browser. I know that listing by matching regular expression would be too long (and be a DOS yeah ). I was just wondering if there are any ways to do it. If not I won't worry about it.

Comment: Without help in some kind (by webserver, administrative interfaces (ie WMI) or a webservice running in the web) you won't probably be able to get a directory listing in a fast and reliable way. Is it your website? If so, I would go for a webservice.

Comment: you might be right. I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: Will post my last comment as an answer, so this can be closed if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without help in some kind (by web server, administrative interfaces (ie WMI) or a web service running in the web) you won't probably be able to get a directory listing in a fast and reliable way. Is it your website? If so, I would go for a web service.